# How to convert python integers to a number in ZP group in Charm-Crypto?

Tags: python, encoding, cryptography, integer, charm-crypto

I want to convert an integer to a number in ZP group. I have written following code but it is returning a number of `<class 'integer.Element'>` type. Can someone tell me how can I do this?

```
num= 193857774579808121448
bb= Conversion. IP2OS(num,  20)
ele= Conversion.OS2IP(bb, element=True)
```

Comment: What happens when you do this? Are there any errors?

Comment: It does not generate any errors but the resulting element is not an element of Zr group and it is still a python integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PairingGroup.init(ZR, 193857774579808121448)` to convert a Python integer to a Charm element in Z<sub>r</sub>.

Example:

```
>>> from charm.toolbox.pairinggroup import PairingGroup,ZR,G1,G2,GT,pair
>>> group = PairingGroup('SS512')
>>> i = group.init(ZR, 193857774579808121448)
>>> i
193857774579808121448
>>> type(i)
<class 'pairing.Element'>
```

Keep in mind that the Python integer that you pass in must be smaller than `r` which is shown in the pairing parameters (i.e. `group.__dict__`). Charm will silently apply the modulo operator to the passed number so that the resulting element is in Z<sub>r</sub>.